# NFS mounts not visible for other users in system

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, nfs, mount

Recently I faced an issue of limited visibility of mounted NFS shares on windows 2008 server.
Situation is like this:

- as user A I have mounted NFS share (from linux server)
- as User A I'm executing mount or net use and I see that NFS share
- then as user B I'm doing same checks - NFS share not visible

Is there a way to see that share as diff user that did not mount it?

Answer (score 2):

User B could mount it, manually or as a login script. They'll need valid credentials - their own or a shared account.

You can also map a drive as the SYSTEM account so that drive is available to all sessions on the computer, but that's not really the way Windows is meant to work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service/4763324#4763324

Comment: Ok, that works partially for me. It's visible from explorer level for all user but from cmd it's not - and I need to be visible there. Also that share mounted share need to be maped to proper UID/GUID and for user "authority/system" at the moment I don't see possibility to set it up via AD.

Comment: @Adam Is it mounted as a drive or simply a mounted folder?  If it is mounted as a drive letter, it should show in cmd.  Did open the cmd window after the drive was mounted?  If not, close and reopen cmd.  It may see the drive when you reload the environment.  UserID mapping for NFS shares on a Windows server is non-trivial.  Very non-trivial.  It deserves a separate question.  There are so many ways to handle identity management between Linux and Windows hosts on the same network.  Be sure to include your current identity management and how each server uses it in your question.